# How does the experience system work on Flick Kick Football Legends?

Tags: football-legends

I find this game amazing, it is like a soccer-pokemon hybrid. I have been trying to figure out how the experience system work, unfortunately with no success. You might be able to help me.

1. When successfully passing the ball, which player gets the experience, the passer or the receiver?
2. Some players get experience although they did not touch the ball during the whole match. For example the goalie as you can see in the picture below. How is that experience calculated?

Thank you.

[image: XP]